# PHP post variables

Tags: php, session, variables, post

Can you save a variable to post in php to pickup on another page? I only know how to retrieve a post variable, or is this where you should use session instead. I don't want to save my variable on the end of the url and use get.

Comment: Are you calling the other page from the PHP script? If so, how are you doing this? e.g. by calling its URL, or including it in the current script?

Comment: Use session variables instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you might want to use `$_SESSION` variables, instead of `$_POST`.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

Where is the data you're wanting to pickup on the next page coming from? A form? Or what?