# How to Post Textnode From a Page to Another at element With Specific Id Using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

firstpage.html :

```
<body>
<?php
$text = $_POST['text'];
?>
<p style = "color:red; " id = "getext"><?php echo $text; ?></p>
</body>
```

secondpage.php :

```
<body>
<?php
$text = $_POST['text'];
?>
<p style = "color:red; " id = "getext">i want $text var to appear here</p>
</body>
```

I want to post text node from first page to second one in the p element with id "gettext" thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP post variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520611/php-post-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not post, text nodes directly. So we have to change logic for that.

```
<form action = "secondpage.php" method = "POST" onsubmit="return false" name="form1">
<p id="txtNode">textnode</p>
<input type=button onclick="submitForm()" value="Submit">
<input type=hidden id="text" name="text">
</form>
```

Here we have disabled default submit action of form by setting **onsubmit="return false"**, then we have defined **onclick="submitForm()"** for the button which will submit the form. In **submitForm()** function we will copy the text node into a hidden field and submit the form, as shown below :

```
function submitForm(){
var txtNode = document.getElementById("txtNode").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("text").value=txtNode;
document.forms["form1"].submit();
}
```

Then on **secondpage.php**, you will be able to get that value:

```
<?php
$text = isset($_POST['text'])?$_POST['text']:"";
?>
<p style = "color:red; " id = "getext"><?php echo $text; ?></p>
```